# nodejs destructuring variables returning undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, blockchain, publish-subscribe, pubnub

so I am building a blockchain in nodejs and when I run the application, my constructor variables pass undefined, although I made it so it passes down variables as an object in the index file. The following relevant files will be shown below...

PubNub for pubsubbing:

```
const PubNub = require('pubnub');

const credentials = {
  publishKey: 'pub-c-274ab4f3-redacted',
  subscribeKey: 'sub-c-fe7d959c-redacted',
  secretKey: 'sec-c-cannotDisplay'
};

const CHANNELS = {
  TEST: 'TEST',
  BLOCKCHAIN: 'BLOCKCHAIN',
  TRANSACTION: 'TRANSACTION'
};

class PubSub {
  constructor({ blockchain, transactionPool, wallet }) {
    this.blockchain = blockchain;
    this.transactionPool = transactionPool;
    this.wallet = wallet;

    this.pubnub = new PubNub(credentials);
//where you put uuid
    this.pubnub.subscribe({ channels: Object.values(CHANNELS) });

    this.pubnub.addListener(this.listener());
  }

  broadcastChain() {
    this.publish({
      channel: CHANNELS.BLOCKCHAIN,
      message: JSON.stringify(this.blockchain.chain)
    });
  }

  broadcastTransaction(transaction) {
    this.publish({
      channel: CHANNELS.TRANSACTION,
      message: JSON.stringify(transaction)
    });
  }

  subscribeToChannels() {
    this.pubnub.subscribe({
      channels: [Object.values(CHANNELS)]
    });
  }

  listener() {
    return {
      message: messageObject => {
        const { channel, message } = messageObject;

        console.log(`Message received. Channel: ${channel}. Message: ${message}`);
        const parsedMessage = JSON.parse(message);

        switch(channel) {
          case CHANNELS.BLOCKCHAIN:
            this.blockchain.replaceChain(parsedMessage, true, () => {
              this.transactionPool.clearBlockchainTransactions(
                { chain: parsedMessage.chain }
              );
            });
            break;
          case CHANNELS.TRANSACTION:
            if (!this.transactionPool.existingTransaction({
              inputAddress: this.wallet.publicKey
            })) {
              this.transactionPool.setTransaction(parsedMessage);
            }
            break;
          default:
            return;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  publish({ channel, message }) {
    // there is an unsubscribe function in pubnub
    // but it doesn't have a callback that fires after success
    // therefore, redundant publishes to the same local subscriber will be accepted as noisy no-ops
    this.pubnub.publish({ message, channel });//channel,message
  }

  broadcastChain() {
    this.publish({
      channel: CHANNELS.BLOCKCHAIN,
      message: JSON.stringify(this.blockchain.chain)
    });
  }

  broadcastTransaction(transaction) {
    this.publish({
      channel: CHANNELS.TRANSACTION,
      message: JSON.stringify(transaction)
    });
  }
}
const testPubSub = new PubSub()
{
  testPubSub.publish({channel: CHANNELS.TEST, message: 'testing'});
}

module.exports = PubSub;
```

Main index:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const express = require('express');
const request = require('request');
const path = require('path');
const Blockchain = require('./blockchain');
const PubSub = require('./app/pubsub');
const TransactionPool = require('./wallet/transaction-pool');
const Wallet = require('./wallet');
const TransactionMiner = require('./app/transaction-miner');
const PubSubNub = require('./app/pubsub.pubnub');
//127.0.0.1:6379
const isDevelopment = process.env.ENV === 'development';
//TRY PUBNUB (comment out)
/*const REDIS_URL = isDevelopment ?
  'redis://127.0.0.1:6379' : //try 6379 19289
  'redis://h:p602b6838e89da65c8c4d29a6a4f954452d1ece59c10b27a29ebf9808721cb8e2@ec2-35-153-115-238.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9819'//19289
*/  
const DEFAULT_PORT = 3000;
const ROOT_NODE_ADDRESS = 
`http://localhost:${DEFAULT_PORT}`;

const app = express();
const blockchain = new Blockchain();
const transactionPool = new TransactionPool();
const wallet = new Wallet();
//const pubsub = new PubSub({ blockchain, transactionPool, redisUrl: REDIS_URL });//redis
const pubsub = new PubSubNub({ blockchain, transactionPool, wallet }); // for PubNub //change back to PubSub if issues arise
const transactionMiner = new TransactionMiner({ blockchain, transactionPool, wallet, pubsub });

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/dist')));
//endpoint
app.get('/api/blocks', (req, res) => {
  res.json(blockchain.chain);
});

app.get('/api/blocks/length', (req, res) => {
  res.json(blockchain.chain.length);
});

app.get('/api/blocks/:id', (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  const { length } = blockchain.chain;

  const blocksReversed = blockchain.chain.slice().reverse();

  let startIndex = (id-1) * 5;
  let endIndex = id * 5;

  startIndex = startIndex < length ? startIndex : length;
  endIndex = endIndex < length ? endIndex : length;

  res.json(blocksReversed.slice(startIndex, endIndex));
});

app.post('/api/mine', (req, res) => {
  const { data } = req.body;

  blockchain.addBlock({ data });

  pubsub.broadcastChain();

  res.redirect('/api/blocks');
});

app.post('/api/transact', (req, res) => {
  const { amount, recipient } = req.body;

  let transaction = transactionPool
    .existingTransaction({ inputAddress: wallet.publicKey });

  try {
    if (transaction) {
      transaction.update({ senderWallet: wallet, recipient, amount });
    } else {
      transaction = wallet.createTransaction({
        recipient,
        amount,
        chain: blockchain.chain
      });
    }
  } catch(error) {
    return res.status(400).json({ type: 'error', message: error.message });
  }

  transactionPool.setTransaction(transaction);

  pubsub.broadcastTransaction(transaction);

  res.json({ type: 'success', transaction });
});

app.get('/api/transaction-pool-map', (req, res) => {
  res.json(transactionPool.transactionMap);
});

app.get('/api/mine-transactions', (req, res) => {
  transactionMiner.mineTransactions();

  res.redirect('/api/blocks');
});

app.get('/api/wallet-info', (req, res) => {
  const address = wallet.publicKey;

  res.json({
    address,
    balance: Wallet.calculateBalance({ chain: blockchain.chain, address })
  });
});

app.get('/api/known-addresses', (req, res) => {
  const addressMap = {};

  for (let block of blockchain.chain) {
    for (let transaction of block.data) {
      const recipient = Object.keys(transaction.outputMap);

      recipient.forEach(recipient => addressMap[recipient] = recipient);
    }
  }

  res.json(Object.keys(addressMap));
});

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client/dist/index.html'));
});

const syncWithRootState = () => {
  request({ url: `${ROOT_NODE_ADDRESS}/api/blocks` }, (error, response, body) => {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
      const rootChain = JSON.parse(body);

      console.log('replace chain on a sync with', rootChain);
      blockchain.replaceChain(rootChain);
    }
  });

  request({ url: `${ROOT_NODE_ADDRESS}/api/transaction-pool-map` }, (error, response, body) => {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
      const rootTransactionPoolMap = JSON.parse(body);

      console.log('replace transaction pool map on a sync with', rootTransactionPoolMap);
      transactionPool.setMap(rootTransactionPoolMap);
    }
  });
};

if (isDevelopment) {
  const walletFoo = new Wallet();
  const walletBar = new Wallet();

  const generateWalletTransaction = ({ wallet, recipient, amount }) => {
    const transaction = wallet.createTransaction({
      recipient, amount, chain: blockchain.chain
    });

    transactionPool.setTransaction(transaction);
  };

  const walletAction = () => generateWalletTransaction({
    wallet, recipient: walletFoo.publicKey, amount: 5
  });

  const walletFooAction = () => generateWalletTransaction({
    wallet: walletFoo, recipient: walletBar.publicKey, amount: 10
  });

  const walletBarAction = () => generateWalletTransaction({
    wallet: walletBar, recipient: wallet.publicKey, amount: 15
  });

  for (let i=0; i<20; i++) {
    if (i%3 === 0) {
      walletAction();
      walletFooAction();
    } else if (i%3 === 1) {
      walletAction();
      walletBarAction();
    } else {
      walletFooAction();
      walletBarAction();
    }

    transactionMiner.mineTransactions();
  }
}

let PEER_PORT;

if (process.env.GENERATE_PEER_PORT === 'true') {
  PEER_PORT = DEFAULT_PORT + Math.ceil(Math.random() * 1000);
}

const PORT = process.env.PORT || PEER_PORT || DEFAULT_PORT;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`listening at localhost:${PORT}`);

  if (PORT !== DEFAULT_PORT) {
    syncWithRootState();
  }
});
```

Error log:

```
main@goldengates.club [~/public_html/Cypher-Network]# npm run start

> Cypher-Network@1.0.0 start /home/main/public_html/Cypher-Network
> npm run build-client & node index.js


> Cypher-Network@1.0.0 build-client /home/main/public_html/Cypher-Network
> npm run clean && parcel build client/src/index.html --out-dir client/dist


> Cypher-Network@1.0.0 clean /home/main/public_html/Cypher-Network
> rm -rf .cache client/dist

/home/main/public_html/Cypher-Network/app/pubsub.pubnub.js:16
  constructor({ blockchain, transactionPool, wallet }) {
                ^

TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'blockchain' of 'undefined' as it is undefined.
    at new PubSub (/home/main/public_html/Cypher-Network/app/pubsub.pubnub.js:16:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/main/public_html/Cypher-Network/app/pubsub.pubnub.js:99:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/main/public_html/Cypher-Network/index.js:10:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! Cypher-Network@1.0.0 start: `npm run build-client & node index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the Cypher-Network@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/main/.npm/_logs/2020-03-27T18_49_30_710Z-debug.log
⠋ Building...lscpu: failed to determine number of CPUs: /sys/devices/system/cpu/possible: No such file or directory
✨  Built in 17.71s.

client/dist/src.a02dd135.js.map     ⚠️  1.17 MB     160ms
client/dist/src.a02dd135.js          501.63 KB    17.02s
client/dist/logo.04580eb6.png         50.84 KB     4.37s
client/dist/src.e852c4ed.css.map         957 B       4ms
client/dist/index.html                   454 B     457ms
client/dist/src.e852c4ed.css             454 B     4.86s
```

If there is a need for me to share inherited files, give notice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
class PubSub {
  constructor({ blockchain, transactionPool, wallet }) {
```

and here:

```
const testPubSub = new PubSub()
```

So, for this specific constructor call, the destructuring in the `PubSub` constructor amounts to

```
const { blockchain, transactionPool, wallet } = undefined;
```

And you can't do that, neither with `undefined` nor with `null`. You need to either, call `new PubSub(/*...*/)` with correct parameters, or maybe use default parameter values.